# HTML Row auto-resize to fit window

Tags: asp.net, html, resize, telerik, row

I have a HTML table (black) which fills a window (blue). The table contains two rows.
When I resize the window, row 1 (red) height must be variable and row 2 (green) height constant.

Row 1 content is are dynamically generated (a tab strip and a tree view - both Telerik).

Row 2 contains two columns.

In other words, how to make the row 1 autosize itself when the windows is resizes?

[image]

All I have done, so far, is this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="height:100%;vertical-align:top;overflow:auto">
        <td colspan="2">
            <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="RadTabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" Width="100%" Height="100%">
                <Tabs>
                    <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Tab1" Selected="True">
                    </telerik:RadTab>
                    <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Tab2">
                    </telerik:RadTab>
                </Tabs>
            </telerik:RadTabStrip>
            <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" Width="100%" SelectedIndex="0" Height="100%">
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView1" runat="server" Height="100%" style="border: 1px solid grey">
                    <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server"></telerik:RadTreeView>
                </telerik:RadPageView>
                <telerik:RadPageView ID="RadPageView2" runat="server" Height="100%" style="border: 1px solid grey">
                    <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView2" runat="server"></telerik:RadTreeView>
                </telerik:RadPageView>
            </telerik:RadMultiPage>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font: normal 12px arial; text-align: left;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Do something when checked." AutoPostBack="true" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            <telerik:RadButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClicked="windowClose" UseSubmitBehavior="false">
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try ,style="width:10%;height:20px"

Comment: Where? <table style="width:10%;height:20px;">? Doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer for a simple question. Set a relative height (%) for first row and a fixed height (px) for second row!

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr style="height:100%;vertical-align:top;overflow:auto">
          ....
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100px;">
          ....
    </tr>
</table>
```

Adjust the `100px` to whatever height Row 2 must have.

Also, set the table's height to the window's height using javascript and onload method.

The javascript would be:

```
document.onload  = new function(){
```

var theTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
        theTable.style.height = (document.height)+"px";
    }

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yMZnY/).

Comment: How can I set the table's height to the window's height using javascript and onload method? Any example would be good..

Comment: I added the javascript you would need.

Answer (score 0):

add this on whichever row you wish to auto -size , even height also you can give it % rather than PX ,like

```
<tr style="width:10%;height:20px;">
    <td style="font: normal 12px arial; text-align: left;">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Do something when checked." AutoPostBack="true" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right">
        <telerik:RadButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClicked="windowClose" UseSubmitBehavior="false">
        </telerik:RadButton>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It doesn't work! I need the widht on both Rows to be 100%. That's why I have: <table style="width:100%;">. I need the first row HEIGHT to be variable (to fit the window height) and the second row HEIGHT to be fixed. You made the second row height 10%. Why?

Comment: if you want second row wirth fixed then add height:50px ,change it according to your requirement

Comment: Ok, but what about the first row? I tried <tr style="height:80%;vertical-align:top;">. But it doesn't work.